# Which user is "the most" legendary across the whole network of sites?

Tags: discussion, badges, daily-reputation-badges

I have seen [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253849/arent-the-mortarboard-epic-or-legendary-badges-useless-on-a-meta-site) - nicely laying out that even meta sites (with assumed low "traffic") can have *legendary* users.

Simply wondering now: is there a list somewhere providing a "ranking" of users that hold "the most" legendary badges?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It was too much work to not post it but @Glorfindel beat me by a few minutes.

Here is the [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/710580):

(do note this looks at both regular sites **AND** site meta's. The latter might feel strange because site meta's don't show rep but you still earn the reputation related badges)

```sql
-- result table, don't rename and keep the site column
create table #results ( site nvarchar(250)
                       , username nvarchar(35)
                       , accountid int
                       , days int);

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = ''   -- holds build up sql string

-- build one biq union sql, for each db
select @sql = @sql 
+ iif( len(@sql) > 1 
     , 'union'
     , 'insert into #results'
) +
-- here goes the per site query, fully qualify the database objects
N'
select ''' + name + '''
     , u.displayname
     , u.accountid
     , datediff(d, u.creationdate, b.[date])
from ' + quotename(name) + '.dbo.badges b 
inner join ' + quotename(name) + '.dbo.users u on u.id = b.userid
where b.name = ''Legendary''
'
from sys.databases
where database_id > 5
-- and (name not like '%.Meta' or name = 'StackExchange.Meta')

--print @sql

-- execute it
exec (@sql)

-- show results
select    
       ( 'https://stackexchange.com/users/' + cast(o.accountid as nvarchar)
       + '|' 
       + (select min(username) from #results r where r.accountid = o.accountid) 
       ) as [Network profile]
      , count(*) as [# times earned]
      , min(days) as [# days to reach]
from #results o
group by accountid
order by count(*) desc
       , min(days) asc

drop table #results
```

Notice that I added the days it took between user joining a site and the actual awarding of the badge. The less days that took makes them even more legendary. Luckily this didn't reveal any weird SEDE madness where users earned the badge before they joined ...

And here are the results when run today:

[image: league of legendary network wide]

Comment: Hey, I beat @rene with SEDE. Do I get a badge for that?

Comment: I especially like the "days" column ;-)

Comment: @Glorfindel well, this one is more.... detailed. So it's a fair game. ;) (buh, both your name and OP's starts with same letter!)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I agree, that's why I have upvoted this post but not my own :P

Comment: 4:4:2, nice numbers!

Answer (score 11):

According to [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/748298/holders-of-a-specific-badge-networkwide?badgename=Legendary), no user on Stack Exchange has more than two legendary badges. That is surprisingly low, but obtaining the badge requires a lot of dedication.

Those users are (at the moment of writing this):

#### Stack Overflow & Meta Stack Exchange

- [Nick Craver](https://stackexchange.com/users/7598/nick-craver) ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/146/legendary?userid=13249) and [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/52/legendary?userid=135201))
- [Bill the Lizard](https://stackexchange.com/users/970/bill-the-lizard) ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/146/legendary?userid=1288) and [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/52/legendary?userid=1288))
- [Oded](https://stackexchange.com/users/1190/oded) ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/146/legendary?userid=1583) and [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/52/legendary?userid=140505))
- [Pekka supports GoFundMonica](https://stackexchange.com/users/63368/pekka) ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/146/legendary?userid=187606) and [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/52/legendary?userid=138112))

#### Stack Overflow & Meta Stack Overflow

- [Martijn Pieters](https://stackexchange.com/users/35417/martijn-pieters) ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/146/legendary?userid=100297) and [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/43/legendary?userid=100297))
- [Servy](https://stackexchange.com/users/1185389/servy) ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/146/legendary?userid=1159478) and [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/43/legendary?userid=1159478))
- [BoltClock](https://stackexchange.com/users/37175/boltclock) ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/146/legendary?userid=106224) and [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/43/legendary?userid=106224))

#### Meta Stack Exchange & Meta Stack Overflow

- [Tim Post](https://stackexchange.com/users/20808/tim-post) ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/52/legendary?userid=50049) and [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/43/legendary?userid=50049))
- [Shog9](https://stackexchange.com/users/620/shog9) ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/52/legendary?userid=811) and [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/43/legendary?userid=811))
- [Glorfindel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/295232/glorfindel) ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/52/legendary?userid=295232) and [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/43/legendary?userid=4751173))

#### Other combinations

- [Aaron Bertrand](https://stackexchange.com/users/24165/aaron-bertrand) ([Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/146/legendary?userid=61305) and [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/badges/27/legendary?userid=1186))
- [janos](https://stackexchange.com/users/322516/janos) ([Stack Overflow](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/badges/27/legendary?userid=12390) and [Code Review](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/146/legendary?userid=641955))
- [Daniel Fischer](https://stackexchange.com/users/996105/daniel-fischer) ([Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/146/legendary?userid=1011995) and [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/43/legendary?userid=83702))
- [egreg](https://stackexchange.com/users/513966/egreg) ([Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/43/legendary?userid=62967) and [TeX - LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/badges/43/legendary?userid=4427))
- [Rand al'Thor](https://stackexchange.com/users/4859979/rand-althor) ([Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/27/legendary?userid=31394) and [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/43/legendary?userid=5373))

#### Honourable mentions

- [Robert Harvey](https://stackexchange.com/users/36137/robert-harvey) has one on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/badges/27/legendary?userid=1204) and [used to have one on Meta Stack Exchange](http://web.archive.org/web/20161225012700/https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/52/legendary?userid=102937) but he deleted his account there.

Jon Skeet is not among them; his legend level is actually *above* "the most legendary".

Comment: Not really surprising. Skeet is Programming God, but on other sites he's just "active", not legendary.

Comment: No, not really. But I'd thought it would be fun to continue the Jon Skeet adoration from the comments through my answer.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Yes. I also didn't expect Jon to show in such a ranking. Now I am wondering: is there a badge for finding a ranking in which Jon doesn't show up?

Comment: @GhostCat sure, Anti Skeet badge. Gold, of course. :-P

Answer (score 5):

More of an addendum, to occasionally keep track of new entries, and (for today) slightly adapted usernames, rerun(s) of renes query, with all "2 legendary badge" holders:

[image: top-legends-jan2020]

Comment: *can't resist upvoting posts which mention me*

Comment: Wow, that's a pretty elite club I'm now part of.