# Who is most "legendary" on the non-meta non-programming part of SE?

Tags: support, badges, daily-reputation-badges

(As a non-programmer) I'd be interested to see a list of who is most "legendary" on the non-programming, non-meta (NPNM) part of the site, defined as looking only at "legendary" (L) badges gained on non-meta subsites other than Stack Overflow and Software Engineering.

- Have any users gained two NPNM L badges yet? If yes, how do they rank by how long they took to win them?
- How do those with at least one NPNM L badge rank by the time they took to win their first one?

Notes

1. This is a followup to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299754/which-user-is-the-most-legendary-across-the-whole-network-of-sites/341678#341678)
2. I am the same person as "JohnRichardWillis" but I forgot the passwords both for that account and for the email account I used for it, and therefore I couldn't log in and delete my first effort to post this question, which was as an answer to the other question, a form which I am advised was incorrect. My apologies. Please can someone delete that answer and also that account - thanks.

Comment: That first non-answer is gone already ...

Answer (score 5):

I've modified [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/748298/holders-of-a-specific-badge-networkwide?badgename=Legendary) to show the sites where users obtained their badges.

[Rand al'Thor](https://stackexchange.com/users/4859979/rand-althor) earned his badges on Science Fiction & Fantasy and Puzzling Stack Exchange. I think he qualifies.

Another candidate (depending on if you consider TeX to be programming or just 'markup') would be [egreg](https://stackexchange.com/users/513966/egreg) who is legendary on Mathematics and TeX - LaTeX.

(I'll leave it to rene to answer your second question.)